# BigWig circular plot representation

Tags: bigwig

I would like to ask if anyone knows or has experience in representing BigWig signals in a circular plot? I mean like IGV but in circular plot not linear. Or any library that can be used in plotting BigWig signals especially in Javascript?

I appreciate any suggestion,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

circosJS should probably work well, based on your requirements: https://github.com/nicgirault/circosJS

I posted a short Observable notebook that shows what calls could be used to bring data from remote bigWig files into a circosJS plot:

https://observablehq.com/@alexpreynolds/rendering-bigwig-file-data-in-a-circular-representation

It is less intended as an explicit how-to in Javascript, than as a starting point for the end user with some of the function calls and data scale issues involved. Hopefully it can be useful to the reader for exploratory purposes.

Comment: Does it take bigwig file without any conversion to tabulated format?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, but you could probably use https://github.com/GMOD/bbi-js as a file parser, get the data you need asynchronously, and feed it to circosJS to render.

Comment: Thank you very much on your suggestion, I will give it a try and see if it works.